# Mixing a trait into its own outer class

Tags: scala

Consider some class with multiple inner classes. Common functionality is is factored out into a trait.

```
case class A[T](a: T) {
    case class B(b: T) extends Inner
    case class C(c: T) extends Inner

    trait Inner {
        case class D(d: T)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to mix trait `Inner` into its own parent, class `A`?

```
// compile error "this can be used only in a class, object, or template.
case class A[T](a: T) extends this.Inner {
  ...
}

// compile error "not found: value self"
case class A[T](a: T) extends self.Inner { self =>
  ...
}

// compile error "illegal cyclic reference involving class A"
case class A[T](a: T) extends A[T]#Inner {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the `Inner` trait to be on a companion Object?

Comment: `Inner` references the parent instance. It must be defined within the class. In this example it only reference the type variable `T` but it might also reference the instance variable `a`.

Comment: Then create a trait `AnotherTrait[T] { def a: T }` that is extended by `A` and used as a self type on `Inner`.

Comment: Hmmm, but then `B` and `C` couldn't extend `Inner` anymore. I see the conundrum.

Comment: An inner class is mostly just sugar for a class with the parent as  a member; you could write that out "by hand": `trait Inner[T] { val parent: A[T] }; case class A[T](a: T) extends Inner { val parent = this }; case class B[T](b: T, parent: A[T]) extends Inner[T]` and so on.